# How to draw a circle pixel by pixel?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cgcontext

I am able to draw a square pixel by pixel as below

```
for(int i=0 ;i<drawbox.size.width/2;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<drawbox.size.height/2; j++)
        {
                 Point.y++;
                 NSLog(@"point:%f,%f",Point.x,Point.y);  
        }
        Point.x++;
    }
```

Here drawrect is CGRect and Point is the CGPoint I am using to draw pixel by pixel

I iterate over this and find a square to be made. This square is filled with each pixel so it just not draw a square with border but it includes all pixels within the square.

I want the same thing but for circle (filled circle's pixels).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Loop over the angle in a [cylindrical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) and translate each point into cartesian coordinates (x and y)

Answer (score 1):

Override your drawRect with following code :

You need to take care of 5 things :

`SIDE_WEITH` = Width of Circle,

`Color constants` :

_r = Red

_g = Green

_b = Blue

_a = Alpha

And set Progress as per your need : `_progress`

That it.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
  [super drawRect:rect];

////    [image drawInRect:rect];

// find the radius and position for the largest circle that fits in the UIView's frame.
int radius, x, y;
int offset = SIDE_WEITH;

// in case the given frame is not square (oblong) we need to check and use the shortest side as our radius.
CGRect frame = self.frame;
if (frame.size.width > frame.size.height) {
    radius = frame.size.height;
    // we want our circle to be in the center of the frame.
    int delta = frame.size.width - radius;
    x = delta/2 - 1;
    y = 0;
} else {
    radius = frame.size.width;
    int delta = frame.size.height - radius;
    y = delta/2 - 1;
    x = 0;
}

// store the largest circle's position and radius in class variable.
_outerCircleRect = CGRectMake(x, y, radius, radius);
// store the inner circles rect, this inner circle will have a radius 10pixels smaller than the outer circle.
// we want to the inner circle to be in the middle of the outer circle.
//_innerCircleRect = CGRectMake(x+offset, y+offset, radius-2*offset , radius-2*offset);
_innerCircleRect = CGRectMake(x+offset, y+offset, radius-2*offset , radius-2*offset);

// get the drawing canvas (CGContext):
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// save the context's previous state:
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// our custom drawing code will go here:

// Draw the gray background for our progress view:

// gradient properties:
CGGradientRef myGradient;
// You need tell Quartz your colour space (how you define colours), there are many colour spaces: RGBA, black&white...
CGColorSpaceRef myColorspace;
// the number of different colours
size_t num_locations = 3;
// the location of each colour change, these are between 0 and 1, zero is the first circle and 1 is the end circle, so 0.5 is in the middle.
CGFloat locations[3] = { 0.0, 0.5 ,1.0 };
// this is the colour components array, because we are using an RGBA system each colour has four components (four numbers associated with it).
CGFloat components[12] = {
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9,    // Start colour
    0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, // middle colour
    0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.9
}; // End colour

myColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components,locations, num_locations);

// gradient start and end points
CGPoint myStartPoint, myEndPoint;
CGFloat myStartRadius, myEndRadius;
myStartPoint.x = _innerCircleRect.origin.x + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myStartPoint.y = _innerCircleRect.origin.y + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myEndPoint.x = _innerCircleRect.origin.x + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myEndPoint.y = _innerCircleRect.origin.y + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myStartRadius = _innerCircleRect.size.width/2 ;
myEndRadius = _outerCircleRect.size.width/2;

// draw the gradient.
/*CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context,
 myGradient,
 myStartPoint, myStartRadius, myEndPoint, myEndRadius, 0);
 CGGradientRelease(myGradient);*/

// draw outline so that the edges are smooth:

// set line width
//CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1);
// set the colour when drawing lines R,G,B,A. (we will set it to the same colour we used as the start and end point of our gradient )
/*CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.4,0.4,0.4,0.9);

 // draw an ellipse in the provided rectangle
 CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, _outerCircleRect);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);*/

/*CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, _innerCircleRect);
 CGContextStrokePath(context);*/


// Draw the progress:

// First clip the drawing area:
// save the context before clipping
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context,
                     _outerCircleRect.origin.x + _outerCircleRect.size.width/2, // move to the top center of the outer circle
                     _outerCircleRect.origin.y +1); // the Y is one more because we want to draw inside the bigger circles.
// add an arc relative to _progress
CGContextAddArc(context,
                _outerCircleRect.origin.x + _outerCircleRect.size.width/2,
                _outerCircleRect.origin.y + _outerCircleRect.size.width/2,
                _outerCircleRect.size.width/2-1,
                -M_PI/2,
                (-M_PI/2 + _progress*2*M_PI), 0);
CGContextAddArc(context,
                _outerCircleRect.origin.x + _outerCircleRect.size.width/2,
                _outerCircleRect.origin.y + _outerCircleRect.size.width/2,
                _outerCircleRect.size.width/2 - 9,
                (-M_PI/2 + _progress*2*M_PI),
                -M_PI/2, 1);
// use clode path to connect the last point in the path with the first point (to create a closed path)
CGContextClosePath(context);
// clip to the path stored in context
CGContextClip(context);

// Progress drawing code comes here:

// set the gradient colours based on class variables.
CGFloat components2[12] = {  _r, _g, _b, _a, // Start color
    ((_r + 0.5 > 1) ? 1 : (_r+0.5) ) , ((_g + 0.5 > 1) ? 1 : (_g+0.5) ), ((_b + 0.5 > 1) ? 1 : (_b+0.5) ), ((_a + 0.5 > 1) ? 1 : (_a+0.5)),
    _r, _g, _b, _a }; // End color

myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (myColorspace, components2,locations, num_locations);

myStartPoint.x = _innerCircleRect.origin.x + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myStartPoint.y = _innerCircleRect.origin.y + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myEndPoint.x = _innerCircleRect.origin.x + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myEndPoint.y = _innerCircleRect.origin.y + _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
// set the radias for start and endpoints a bit smaller, because we want to draw inside the outer circles.
myStartRadius = _innerCircleRect.size.width/2;
myEndRadius = _outerCircleRect.size.width/2;

CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context,
                            myGradient,
                            myStartPoint, myStartRadius, myEndPoint, myEndRadius, 0);

// release myGradient and myColorSpace
CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorspace);


// draw circle on the outline to smooth it out.

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, _r,_g,_b,_a);

// draw an ellipse in the provided rectangle
CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, _outerCircleRect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, _innerCircleRect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);


//restore the context and remove the clipping area.
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

// restore the context's state when we are done with it:
CGContextRestoreGState(context);


/*CGPathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathAddEllipseInRect(circlePath , NULL , rect);
 CAShapeLayer *circle = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
 circle.path = circlePath;
 circle.opacity = 0.5;
 [self.imageView.layer addSublayer:circle];
 CGPathRelease( circlePath );
 [circle release];*/
}
```

Comment: I need to draw it pixel by pixel. That is why I need loop. CGContext is not required in my case

Comment: You can set progress depending on your pixel, here progress is from 0.0 to 1.0, so for example at 0.5 its half circle. And you can have pixel by pixel circle.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0; i<drawbox.size.width/2; i++) {
    for (int j=(int)(-drawbox.size.height/4.0 * sqrt(1 - pow(4.0*i/drawbox.size.width - 1, 2)) + drawbox.size.height/4.0); 
             j<=(int)(drawbox.size.height/4.0 * sqrt(1 - pow(4.0*i/drawbox.size.width - 1, 2)) + drawbox.size.height/4.0); 
             j++) 
    {
         Point.y++;
         NSLog(@"point:%f,%f",Point.x,Point.y);  
    }
    tStartPoint.x++;
}
```

This will draw an ellipse with the same center the rectangle has you drow in the question.

Comment: Well, I added some endlines and spaces and also simplified my formula a little bit.

Comment: This is not working as it is drawing two parallel lines instead of circle